# Python: unsigned 32 bit bitwise arithmetic

Tags: python, math

Trying to answer to another post whose solution deals with IP addresses and netmasks, I got stuck with plain bitwise arithmetic.

Is there a standard way, in Python, to carry on bitwise AND, OR, XOR, NOT operations assuming that the inputs are "32 bit" (maybe negative) integers or longs, and that the result must be a long in the range [0, 2**32]?

In other words, I need a working Python counterpart to the C bitwise operations between  unsigned longs.

EDIT: the specific issue is this:

```
>>> m = 0xFFFFFF00   # netmask 255.255.255.0
>>> ~m
-4294967041L         # wtf?! I want 255
```

Comment: I imagine Pythons loose typing would play hell with any algorithm like this... I want to see one too, just out of curiousity.

Comment: As of Python 3.3, some users encountering this might be interested in [the ipaddress module](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/ipaddress).

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can mask everything by `0xFFFFFFFF`:

```
>>> m = 0xFFFFFF00
>>> allf = 0xFFFFFFFF
>>> ~m & allf
255L
```

Comment: This strategy also helps with [bash arithmetic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222379/how-to-efficiently-convert-long-int-to-dotted-quad-ip-in-bash).

Comment: You're doing one more operation than necessary. ANDing a NOT is the same as an XOR. So, `m ^ allf` is what you need.

Comment: @mlefavor I don't know where you got the idea that `~a & b` is the same as `a ^ b`.  It's not in general.

Comment: I guess that was overexuberant of me. But I think it's true in the case of 0xFFFFFFFF.

Comment: See this wiki for the reason for needing the mask:
https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators

In a nutshell, negative numbers are treated as if they have an infinite number of leading 1s. The bitmask shaves off all but the number of digits that you want.

Answer (score 63):

You can use [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-ctypes.html) and its `c_uint32`:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> m = 0xFFFFFF00
>>> ctypes.c_uint32(~m).value
255L
```

So what I did here was casting `~m` to a C 32-bit unsigned integer and retrieving its value back in Python format.

Answer (score 12):

```
from numpy import uint32
```

Comment: @gerrit Is he referring to the fact that it requires the system to have the numpy module installed whereas ctypes is a part of core python?

Answer (score 6):

You could also xor with 0xFFFFFFFF, which is equivalent to the "unsigned complement".

```
>>> 0xFFFFFF00 ^ 0xFFFFFFFF
255
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a module that I created a long time ago, and it might be of help to you:

[IPv4Utils](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/IPv4_Utils/0.35)

It provides at least a `CIDR` class with subnet arithmetic. Check the test cases at the end of the module for examples.