# Python invert a number

Tags: python, numbers, bit

First of all I'm not a Python expert, so here is my topic:

I want to invert a number, let say `number = "ABCD123"` (yes this is a string but I need to do it this way ...), the problem is that I'm not really satisfy with the way Python deal with the inversion, for example `~0xABCD123` is `-180146468` and I don't want the MSB but only the "current" bits to be inverted. I can go with something like `~0xABCD123 & 0XFFFFFFF` but the size of the number can actually change...

**Question**

Is there a way to dynamically "cast" or remove the bit sign in Python with the operator `~`

Comment: And if you want to do exactly what you have said, why not AND it with 16**(length of your string) - 1?

Comment: for example I have `0XD5` wich is binary `11010101`, when I do `~0xD5` the result is `-214` but I want the result to be the invert like `00101010`. Maybe I'm misunderstanding the concept of Python's `~`

Comment: In that case, you are better off XORing with FF..F. I don't think there are unsigned integers in Python.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210629/python-unsigned-32-bit-bitwise-arithmetic. Possible duplicate! Check the 2nd answer with ctypes conversion...

Comment: I feel pretty stupid didn't think of XORing... it work well now :) thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple hack:

```
def invert_int(n):
    number_bit_len = n.bit_length()
    max_val = (2 ** number_bit_len) - 1
    return ~n & max_val
```

Comment: You can replace the first two lines with `n.bit_length()` which is also more reliable with big integers. Also using `2 ** number_bit_len - 1` would work for any integer size, while `math.pow` fails for big enough numbers.

Comment: [`bit_length`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length) is python 3 only

Comment: @lcfseth: Huh. The docs say _"New in version 3.1."_, but you're right, it works.